# Minimum number of steps to sort 3x3 matrix in a specific way

Tags: algorithm, matrix, data-structures

So I started practicing some algorithms and programming before university starts and I ran into this problem:

Given a 3x3 matrix containing the numbers from 0 to 8, find the minimum number of steps required to sort the matrix in the following format:

1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 0

In one move it is only allowed to pick a cell that is adjacent to the cell which contains the 0 and swap those two cells.

Now, I am really stuck with this one and have no idea how to begin. Any tips and ideas to get me started are appreciated.

This is not homework if anyone thinks that way, I am just trying to exercise and by moving to tougher problems I got stuck. I am not looking for anyone to write the code for me, I just need a point in the right direction because I really want to understand the algorithm behind this. Thank you.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle. The version you're dealing with is called the "8-puzzle". Google that and you'll find plenty of resources.

Comment: [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) or [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** This is actually an AI problem, and not a trivial data structure/algorithm problem.

This problem is called the `n-puzzle` problem. The example in your question is the `8-puzzle` problem.

The way to solve this problem is by trying to shuffle the boxes in a way that each step gets you closer to your final goal. Think of this as a Greedy approach (`Best-first search`). The best algorithm to use here is the [A* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).

> We define a state of the game to be the board position, the number of
>   moves made to reach the board position, and the previous state. First,
>   insert the initial state (the initial board, 0 moves, and a null
>   previous state) into a priority queue. Then, delete from the priority
>   queue the state with the minimum priority, and insert onto the
>   priority queue all neighboring states (those that can be reached in
>   one move). Repeat this procedure until the state dequeued is the goal
>   state. The success of this approach hinges on the choice of priority
>   function for a state. We consider two priority functions:
>
> - Hamming priority function. The number of blocks in the wrong position, plus  the number of moves made so far to get to the state. Intutively, a state with a small number of blocks in the wrong position is close to the goal state, and we prefer a state that have been reached using a small number of moves.
> - Manhattan priority function. The sum of the distances (sum of the vertical and horizontal distance) from the blocks to their goal positions, plus the number of moves made so far to get to the state.
>
> For example, the Hamming and Manhattan priorities of the initial state
>   below are 5 and 10, respectively.
>
> ```
>  8  1  3        1  2  3     1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
>  4     2        4  5  6     ----------------------    ----------------------
>  7  6  5        7  8        1  1  0  0  1  1  0  1    1  2  0  0  2  2  0  3
>
>  initial          goal         Hamming = 5 + 0          Manhattan = 10 + 0
> ```
>
> We make a key oberservation: to solve the puzzle from a given state
>   on the priority queue, the total number of moves we need to make
>   (including those already made) is at least its priority, using either
>   the Hamming or Manhattan priority function. (For Hamming priority,
>   this is true because each block that is out of place must move at
>   least once to reach its goal position. For Manhattan priority, this is
>   true because each block must move its Manhattan distance from its goal
>   position. Note that we do not count the blank tile when computing the
>   Hamming or Manhattan priorities.)
>
> Consequently, as soon as we dequeue a state, we have not only
>   discovered a sequence of moves from the initial board to the board
>   associated with the state, but one that makes the fewest number of
>   moves.

([Source](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr10/cos226/assignments/8puzzle.html))

Comment: While this is a nice and +1worthy answer, one can still see it as a "trivial data structure problem": One can still do do a brute-force search where in each step, *all* options are considered. For such a small puzzle, this may still be feasible, but I guess for a 15-puzzle, the state space might already be too large, so that a heuristic there is certainly appropriate (and, given that it is [admissible heuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic), A* also finds the optimal solution)

Comment: When I mentioned "trivial data structure problem" I meant a direct implementation of one of the standard algorithms. But I agree with what you say, a brute force will work, at least for the 8-puzzle.

Comment: Elaborate and clear answer, reading the whole source of this and more about the A* algorithm has helped me solve and understand this. Marked as correct.